# In-App Purchase returning 0

Tags: ios, iphone, storekit, contract

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
```

returned a SKProducstResponse with a products array size of 0. Why is this? If it can't find the product it should return a 0 right? I checked the product ID and it matches the one I have in my itunes connect. Checked the bundle identifier and it matches as well.. And yes, I tested this on a device

UPDATE:

I checked the

response.invalidProductIdentifier
and it returned the productID that I was trying to fetch. I went through this list:

- your app is InApp Purchases enabled? **yes**
- you have an InApp Purchase test account? **yes**
- the product we offer is marked as "Cleared for Sale"? **yes**
- Did you upload the application to iTunes Connect? **no** (don't think it's necessary since 2011, correct me if I am wrong)
- do you generate and install a provisioning profile for the new "App ID"? **yes**
- Does your project is signed with the new provisioning profile? **yes**
- Are you compiling the project for IOS 3.0 or higher? **yes**
- Are you using the full product ID when you make a SKProductRequest? ie for example: com.company.sampleapp.productid? **yes**
- Has it been several hours since you added the products to iTunes Connect? **yes**
- Does the contract payment application in the iTunes Connect is complete?  **NO**

Should I actually have the paid contract in effect in order to have the IAP running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should I actually have the paid contract in effect in order to have the IAP running?
**Yes**